# C#.net Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a function called on change of a value in a dropdown box.

Here is the function:

```
protected void ddlDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
        IServices reg = (IServices)ctx.GetObject("Services");

        if (ddlDistrict.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            Int32 DistrictID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDistrict.SelectedValue);

            ddlTaluka.DataSource = reg.getTalukaList(DistrictID));
            ddlTaluka.DataTextField = "TalukaName";
            ddlTaluka.DataValueField = "TalukaID";
            ddlTaluka.DataBind();
            ddlTaluka.Items.Clear();
            ddlTaluka.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select Taluka --", "0"));
        }
        else
        {
            ddlTaluka.Items.Clear();
            ddlTaluka.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("-- Select Taluka --", "0"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
}
```

On change of a value in district dropdown taluka dropdown should be refilled...but 
I am getting error

> Input string was not in correct format

in this line

```
Int32 DistrictID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDistrict.SelectedValue);
```

I am not understanding how to resolve this error.

Comment: When it breaks in the debugger, what is the value of `ddlDistrict.SelectedValue`?  Hold your mouse over it; it will tell you. Then work your way back until you figure out why it is wrong.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart hi..i m getting the selected value as 345;2;University from which 345 is the value of dropdown i selected why are the rest values also coming with it..and how should i pick up only the first value.

Comment: `String.Split` using `';'` as the delimiter.

Comment: Check ddlDistrict.SelectedValue ...........

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your comments, only "345" is in the combobox item you selected.

> @JonathonReinhart hi..i m getting the selected value as
>   345;2;University from which **345 is the value of dropdown i selected**
>   why are the rest values also coming with it..and how should i pick up
>   only the first value.

Try:

```
Int32 DistrictID = int.Parse(ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: hi using ur solution i can the see the value selected "Nashik" but again i get the same error..."Input string not in correct format"

Comment: @user1274646 It appears you may have the same problem if the line immediately following the one outlined above. More specifically: ddlTaluka.DataSource = reg.getTalukaList(Convert.ToInt32(ddlDistrict.SelectedValue));

Comment: hey updated the question but the control does not go to that line error is in upper line still

Comment: @user1274646 is the error still being caused by the original line outlined in your question. It seems like a very odd place to have an error as it's pretty straight forward what the code should do. However, I could see if the error were to happen with "reg.getTalukaList(....)". What is "reg.getTalukaList(...)" expecting as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much everyone with your  help i finally found the solution...

```
    Int32 DistrictID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDistrict.SelectedValue.Split(";".ToCharArray())[0]);
```

Special thanks to @JonathanReinhart